# Can't load Image HTTP

Tags: react-native

I can't load this image, help me please!
My info.plist >

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

my Code >

```
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Image 
        source={{uri: 'http://ro-character-simulator.ratemyserver.net/charsim.php?gender=1&job=40&hair=1&viewid=0&location=256&direction=0&action=1&hdye=1&dye=0&framenum=0&bg=0&cart=&mount=0&shield=0&weapon=0&animate=1&rand=9725591', width: 50, height: 50}}/>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to allow form Xcode settings.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one more key in your `Info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```